# Седьмой десяток разменял

Tags: идиомы

Сколько человеку может быть лет, если о нем говорят, что он разменял седьмой десяток. И почему именно разменял?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Человек прожил 60 лет, полные шесть десятков. Начался седьмой десяток. Этот десяток, скажем, за день до шестидесятилетия был целый, неразменянный. Вот и получается, что, вступая в новое десятилетие, человек разменивает его на дни, месяцы, годы...

Сколько человеку может быть лет? Выражение с "разменял" само по себе не говорит о точном количестве лет. Может быть 60 лет, если человек вчера или два месяца назад праздновал день рождения, а может и больше — например, в разговоре один другому говорит: "Он уже три года назад седьмой десяток разменял".